# 'numpy' has no attribute 'core'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow and when calling it I received some errors messages related to numpy.
The last one, that I can not fix is:[image]

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'core'
```

I obtain this message either importing tensorflow or importing numpy.

I have tried to update numpy in the Anaconda Prompt by:

```
 (base) C:\Users\Paisa>pip install --upgrade numpy
```

proposed in [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43578533/attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-core)  and I obtained the following message:

```
> Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in c:\users\paisa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.16.0)
```

I shall appreciate any help to fix this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are installing Tensorflow via pip, the dependencies of a package ( in this case numpy , scipy , h5py etc. ) will not be installed. There might be some conflicts with versions of a specific package.

- For pip, you can try uninstalling everything and installing back.
- An alternative is to conda in anaconda envs. Conda will install all required packages at once without any need to install them individually.

  conda install tensorflow

Comment: Try installing using conda and let me know if it works :-)